# Spell slots without spells of the same level known

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, sorcerer

A fourth level crossblooded sorcerer can cast at least three spells of second level, yet due to being crossblooded, knows one less spell of each level than a standard sorcerer. In particular, at fourth level, the sorcerer knows precisely zero 2nd level spells.

Does the sorcerer still have access to their second level spell slots?

(If yes, then there is another question which concerns using those slots: [Lower spells in higher spell slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3510/) )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**.
If the character options do not change the number of spells slots per day, only the spells known, then the character would still have those slots. You would be filling them with lower level spells or spells under the effects of metamagic feats.